# Writing text within a list

Tags: html, html-lists

I am trying to write my code to be as semantic as possible and am wondering if it is more correct to write text within a list item as...

```
<li>
    <p>This is my text</p>
    <p>This is another bit of text</p>
</li>
```

or

```
<li>
    This is my text
    <br />
    <br />
    This is another bit of text
</li>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do as you would do as if you had some text directly in the body. So, use `h1`, `h2` etc for headings and use `p` for paragraphs. So to answer your question, I would go for option one and use `<br/>` within the text if you need so but wrap it with the `p` element.

Also, you can take a look at the brand new [html 5 elements](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_new_elements.asp) to give your text more meaning.

Answer (score 1):

If "your texts" are paragraphs, they should go into `p` tags, when it comes to semantics.